# Как обратиться к i-ой букве в элементе типа string

Tags: c++, строки

Есть элемент типа string, как обратиться к его i-ой букве

Comment: Как обычно :) - как к `s[i]`

Comment: @Harry Скорее, ``s[i-1]``. Буквы, в отличие от элементов, нумеруются с 1, а не с 0.

Comment: @Harry зависит от кодировки. Может там мультибайтовая строка.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо)

Comment: @Эникейщик Так никто и не говорил, что 1-based.

Comment: @bipll Явно - не говорил. Но чтобы обратиться к первой букве (i = 1), нужно использовать ``s[0]`` (``s[i-1]``), а не ``s[i]``, как предлагается в первом комментарии).

Comment: Не знаю, как программист на C++, я считаю, сто строка начинается с нулевой буквы, потом идет первая и так далее...

Comment: О каких "буквах" идет речь? > Буквы, в отличие от элементов
 ```std::string``` - контейнер не меньше, чем ```std::vector``` (например).

Answer (score 2):

1) Если string содержит только латинские буквы, либо символы в 8-битной кодировке (Win1251, к примеру), то обратиться к i-ой букве можно как str[i].

2) Если string содержит буквы национальных алфавитов, то это UTF-8, и одна буква может занимать от одного до четырех байт. Определить позицию буквы без полного разбора строки (через Unicode code points) невозможно, так что единственным разумным способом будет преобразование строки в UTF-16, после чего к символам можно обращаться как в 1).

Например:

```
string str = u8"Шаланды полные кефали";
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv;
wstring wstr = conv.from_bytes(str);
wchar_t ltr = wstr[2];  // Cyrillic letter 'л'
```

Comment: К сожалению в UTF-16 [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description) все равно останутся...

Comment: UTF-32 устраняет проблемы символов разной длины!

Comment: @avp, только в теории, реально это редчайшие символы которые не встретить в нормальной жизни. Но для перфекционистов можно конвертировать в UTF-32, изменения в коде минимальные.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "This is a text";
char c_IthChar = str[1];
cout << c_IthChar;
```

> Вывод: h

Не работает с кириллицей и другими алфавитами где 1 символ занимает больше 1 байта (в кириллице каждый символ = 2 байта).

```
string str = "Это текст";
char c_IthChar = str[1];
cout << c_IthChar;
```

> Вывод: �

Comment: А почему `(char)str[1]` вместо простого `str[1]`?

Comment: Вы правы, можно без него

Comment: _в кириллице каждый символ = 2 байта_ - в общем случае это не так; зависит от кодировки.